# Run domino designer project on another machine

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I'm newbie in domino designer and I made a simple database, if I want to run this project on other machine Waht is configuration that I should make it?

Comment: Put it on a domino server and open it with the other client...

Comment: no I need change encryption and access control but I don't now  how  to make that

Comment: Encryption: File - Application - Properties - Encryption settings. 
Access Control: File - Application - Access Control... But that won't help you, if you don't understand anything about what you are doing (and these two menus are basic basic basic knowledge)

Comment: Try using the above information from Torsten to remove encryption and to give yourself proper access, and maybe read some tutorials on basic Notes/Domino development and security. If you have trouble with this, then update your question to be very specific about what you tried, what you want to happen, and what really happened. Then people can try to help you.